# PHP - usando matriz para operações aritimeticas retiradas de combobox

Tags: php, array, matriz

Bom não sei se alguém já jogou um jogo com sistema de rank, é bem simples para cara divisão de elo custa um preço e isso varia conforme o elo, por exemplo cada tyer no ferro vale 10, mas para ir para o bronze você precisa percorrer o restante ou seja se você esta no ferro 2 você ira passa pelo ferro 1 e depois para o bronze 4 e depois bronze 3 assim sucessivamente conforme a sua escolha, mas o grande porem é que varia o preço conforme o elo, queria conseguir fazer isso em `php`.

Pensei em fazer isso com o que eu aprendi em C, mas não consegui transmitir em `php`

```
elo[0][0]=10;//ferro4

elo[0][1]=10;//ferro3

elo[0][2]=10;//ferro2

elo[0][3]=10;//ferro1

elo[1][1]=15;//bronze4

elo[1][1]=15;//bronze3

elo[1][2]=15;//bronze2

elo[1][3]=15;//bronze1
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <h5>Elo atual</h5>
 <form action="array.php" method="POST">
  <select name="eloi" required>
   <option selected disabled value="">Elo</option>
   <option value="1">Ferro</option>
   <option value="2">Bronze</option>
   <option value="3">Prata</option>
   <option value="4">Ouro</option>
   <option value="5">Platina</option>
  </select>
  <select name="tyeri" required>
   <option selected disabled value="">Tier</option>ss
   <option value="1">IV</option>
   <option value="2">III</option>
   <option value="3">II</option>
   <option value="4">I</option>
  </select>

  <h5>Elo desejado</h5>
  <select name="elof" required>
   <option selected disabled value="">Elo</option>
   <option value="1">Ferro</option>
   <option value="2">Bronze</option>
   <option value="3">Prata</option>
   <option value="4">Ouro</option>
   <option value="5">Platina</option>
  </select>
  <select name="tyerf" required>
   <option selected disabled value="">Tier</option>ss
   <option value="1">IV</option>
   <option value="2">III</option>
   <option value="3">II</option>
   <option value="4">I</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="bot" value="enviar">

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso é seu código php? `elo[0][0]=10;//ferro4
elo[0][1]=10;//ferro3
elo[0][2]=10;//ferro2
elo[0][3]=10;//ferro1
elo[1][1]=15;//bronze4
elo[1][1]=15;//bronze3
elo[1][2]=15;//bronze2
elo[1][3]=15;//bronze1`

Comment: é um exemplo se fosse em linguagem C, no php teria q usar foreach

Comment: Pelo que entendi pra aumentar o elo tem que compra ou estou errado?

Comment: s, serio como uma olimpiada vc pega medalha de bronze e quer a de ouro mas para chegar ao ouro vc tem q comprar a de prata então vc paga pela de ouro e a de prata que esta no caminho

Comment: Criar variable coins. Cada minuto aumenta.